How to ignore "-" symbol in REGEXP_REPLACE
I have the following REGEXP_REPLACE that is working as expected:
select REGEXP_REPLACE(ppa.name,'[^0-9A-Za-z]','_') AS project_name

Is there a way to ignore "-" symbols? For instance, if there is a record such as:
PJ3456#3$4-6565

Replace as:
PJ3456_3_4-6565

Essentially, I need it replace everything as it has been doing, but ignore dashes (-).

Include - as the last term in the (negated) character class:
select REGEXP_REPLACE(ppa.name,'[^0-9A-Za-z-]','_') AS project_name
from   ppa;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE ppa (name) AS
  SELECT 'PJ3456#3$4-6565' FROM DUAL

Outputs:



PROJECT_NAME




PJ3456_3_4-6565



(Note: - could also be included as the first term, but if you want to include ] in the character class then ] has to go first and - must then be last so it is a good habit to always put - last so that you are consistent.)
fiddle
